Is this well structured latin, also want to see if online sources got me close on english meaning I was going for
Is this well structured/idiomatic vulgar latin, and how would you write out the english meaning?:
In morte et tenebris abscondam lux creationis
EDIT:
Thanks for the replies, I guess I should have just tagged this more properly as english to latin with the below. Do not really have much external context other than it would be sort of half of yin and yang, though that is more holding the heart or seed of light in darkness.
In death and darkness hides the light of creation.

I would translate this as "I, the light of creation, will lose sight [of something] in death and darkness." My guess is that this is not what you were going for.

Whatever “online sources” it were that produced your Latin version, they were not that far off, actually – it is only the verb abscondam that is wrong; the rest looks correct.
The first problem is that it is in the first person singular (either present subjunctive or future tense). The first person singular is the speaker, so this means “I will hide” (or “may I hide” etc.). We need the third person singular, plus we need a simple present indicative, so that would be abscondit, he/she/it hides.
The second problem is that I assume the English “hide” in this context means “to be hidden,” not to hide some unmentioned thing. You can use abscondere reflexively, e.g. lux se abscondit, and in fact this is frequently done, but I think the meaning is then closer to the act of betaking oneself to a hiding-place, not the state of lying in concealment (similarly, the passive, i.e. lux absconditur, is possible, but is closer in meaning to “the light disappears”).
I would therefore recommend the verb latere, which means exactly that, to be hidden, to lurk, etc. You may have heard it in the line Quidquid latet, apparebit (all that lies hidden will come to light) from the famous hymn Dies irae. With that, and caeteris paribus, you get:
In morte et tenebris latet lux creationis.
Independent from considerations of Latin grammar and vocabulary, I would add that I find the idea of a light hiding in darkness implausible; people can hide in darkness and maybe other things, but for a light, I reckon darkness is the one environment where it will surely be conspicuous.
